# How to use Jedis in flink map()

Tags: redis, apache-flink

My code like this:

```
  StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

  env.enableCheckpointing(500);

  DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(getConsumer(TOPIC_1));

  Jedis jedis = new Jedis("master1");
  stream.map(new RichMapFunction<String, String>() {
      @Override
      public String map(String value) throws Exception {
          String result = jedis.hget("rtc", value);
          return result;
      }
  });
```

I want to get some data from Redis in `map()`, but it cannot run,because Jedis.class is not serializable.

How to use not serializable class in `map()`,such as ZkClient,Jedis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All *rich* functions like the `RichMapFunction` have an `open(Configuration)` and `close` call which you can override. These lifecycle methods are called once the function has been deployed to a TaskManager where it is executed.

```
class MyMapFunction extends RichMapFunction<String, String> {

    private transient Jedis jedis;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) {
        // open connection to Redis, for example
        jedis = new Jedis("master1");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // close connection to Redis
        jedis.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me
Whether it is when I compute a data, it will create a redis client, I am afraid this will  impact the performance

Comment: But it will only be executed once at start up time.